# $http.get API response in HTML Table using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to bind the data from URL to the HTML table. But I can't display it. It can be binded below the HTML table. But HTML table is not displaying data from the API.

Here is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://ec2-35-164-0-168.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/panasonic_dubai/_search?q=%2Bdirection%3AIncomming")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response.data;
      },
      function myError(response) {
        $scope.result = response.statusText;
      });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <title>demo</title>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Simple Table</p>
    <table border="1" cellsapcing="5" cellpadding="5" width="400">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Number</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{result.id}}</td>
        <td>{{result.number}}</td>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h3>{{result}}</h3>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need `ng-repeat` to iterate through the `result`.

Answer (score 1):

I glanced at the AJAX response data from http://ec2-35-164-0-168.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/panasonic_dubai/_search?q=%2Bdirection%3AIncomming, it's a little complex, the response is successfully set to "$scope.result", your problem is using wrong binding, "id" & "number" is not a property of "result":

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 22,
        "max_score": 0.6931472,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "12",
                "_score": 0.6931472,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "extension": 105,
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 04:55PM ",
                    "callduration": "00:02:08",
                    "message": "07/12/16 04:55PM 105 02 Incomming 043203074 0:00 00:02:08 TR",
                    "trunk": 2,
                    "tags": [
                        "_dateparsefailure"
                    ],
                    "number": 43203074,
                    "@timestamp": "2017-03-07T15:58:02.292Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "calltype": "TR",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "1.2"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "9",
                "_score": 0.6931472,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "extension": 100,
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 04:51PM ",
                    "callduration": "00:04:44",
                    "message": "07/12/16 04:51PM 100 03 Incomming 067315033 0:00 00:04:44 TR",
                    "trunk": 3,
                    "tags": [
                        "_dateparsefailure"
                    ],
                    "number": 67315033,
                    "@timestamp": "2017-03-07T15:56:38.077Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "calltype": "TR",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "5.2"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "21",
                "_score": 0.6931472,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "extension": 8103,
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 04:47PM",
                    "callduration": "00:00:25",
                    "message": "07/12/16 04:47PM 8103 03 Incomming 067315033 0:00 00:00:25 D0",
                    "trunk": 3,
                    "number": 67315033,
                    "@timestamp": "2016-12-07T11:17:00.000Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "calltype": "D0",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "9"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "8",
                "_score": 0.6931472,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "extension": 8103,
                    "strdatetime": "08/12/16 08:08AM",
                    "callduration": "00:00:20",
                    "message": "08/12/16 08:08AM 8103 02 Incomming 043333099 0:00 00:00:20 D0",
                    "trunk": 2,
                    "number": 43333099,
                    "@timestamp": "2016-12-08T02:38:00.000Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "calltype": "D0",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "5.4"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "10",
                "_score": 0.6931472,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "number": 65620692,
                    "extension": 8103,
                    "@timestamp": "2016-12-07T11:05:00.000Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 04:35PM",
                    "message": "07/12/16 04:35PM 8103 02 Incomming 065620692 0:00 AN",
                    "trunk": 2,
                    "calltype": "AN",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "5.2"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "14",
                "_score": 0.5753642,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "extension": 110,
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 04:36PM ",
                    "callduration": "00:00:48",
                    "message": "07/12/16 04:36PM 110 02 Incomming 065620692 0:00 00:00:48 TR",
                    "trunk": 2,
                    "tags": [
                        "_dateparsefailure"
                    ],
                    "number": 65620692,
                    "@timestamp": "2017-03-07T15:55:31.469Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "calltype": "TR",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "7.2"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "19",
                "_score": 0.5753642,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "extension": 110,
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 05:30PM ",
                    "callduration": "00:02:28",
                    "message": "07/12/16 05:30PM 110 02 Incomming 0558244974 0:00 00:02:28 TR",
                    "trunk": 2,
                    "tags": [
                        "_dateparsefailure"
                    ],
                    "number": 558244974,
                    "@timestamp": "2017-03-07T16:01:37.394Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "calltype": "TR",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "7"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "22",
                "_score": 0.5753642,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "extension": 8103,
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 04:13PM",
                    "callduration": "00:00:10",
                    "message": "07/12/16 04:13PM 8103 01 Incomming 042820811 0:00 00:00:10 D0",
                    "trunk": 1,
                    "number": 42820811,
                    "@timestamp": "2016-12-07T10:43:00.000Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "calltype": "D0",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "9"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "24",
                "_score": 0.5753642,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "number": 67315033,
                    "extension": 8103,
                    "@timestamp": "2016-12-07T11:16:00.000Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 04:46PM",
                    "message": "07/12/16 04:46PM 8103 03 Incomming 067315033 0:00 AN",
                    "trunk": 3,
                    "calltype": "AN",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "19"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pbxdata",
                "_type": "panasonic_dubai",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.5389965,
                "_source": {
                    "ringduration": "0:00",
                    "extension": 8103,
                    "strdatetime": "07/12/16 04:35PM",
                    "callduration": "00:00:27",
                    "message": "07/12/16 04:35PM 8103 02 Incomming 065620692 0:00 00:00:27 D0",
                    "trunk": 2,
                    "number": 65620692,
                    "@timestamp": "2016-12-07T11:05:00.000Z",
                    "port": 9000,
                    "@version": "1",
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "calltype": "D0",
                    "direction": "Incomming",
                    "cost": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

you suppose to out put data from

> result.hits.hits

which is an array, where you can get "_id" and "_source.number" for binding, therefore you should use "[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)" directive to loop over an array.

The following code is tested on my local, but it won't work here because stackoverflow is https but AJAX is http.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <body>
      <title>demo</title>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    
        <p>Simple Table</p>
        <table border="1" cellsapcing="5" cellpadding="5" width="400">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Number</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="hit in result.hits.hits">
            <td>{{hit._id}}</td>
            <td>{{hit._source.number}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    
        <h3>{{result}}</h3>
    
      </div>
      <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
          $http.get(
              "http://ec2-35-164-0-168.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/panasonic_dubai/_search?q=%2Bdirection%3AIncomming"
            )
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.result = response.data;
              },
              function myError(response) {
                $scope.result = response.statusText;
              });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into you response json structure.
Try this:

```
<td ng-repeat="d in result.hits.hits">{{d.id}}</td><td>{{d._source.number}}</td>
```